# React, Material UI Floating Action Buttons and List/ListItem

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I made a simple Material UI list with List and ListItem components.

I've added a Floating Action Button to the lower part of the screen (bottom right). On a small screen, FAB overlays ListItem components.

By default, if I press the FAB button, the onClick of the ListItem line will be activated instead of the onClick of the FAB button.

Is there any way to set the FAB button onClick event, so that the ItemList onClick is ignored?

Example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-wilbur-1fbe8?fontsize=14

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You have a zIndex problem. This should work:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  fabBottom: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    position: "fixed",
    bottom: theme.spacing(6),
    right: theme.spacing(6),
    zIndex: 1000
  }
});
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/fast-dream-8dkh7

Comment: Well spotted! I have edited the post to add an example, awaiting review.

Comment: This worked just fine. Thank you, this was a great help